# Moment of inertia of irregular object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

How could you use a torsional pendulum to determine the rotational inertia of any object that could be mounted on the Rotary Motion Sensor?`

Note: The [Vernier Rotary Motion Sensor](https://www.vernier.com/product/rotary-motion-sensor/) is a bidirectional angle sensor designed to measure rotational or linear position, velocity and acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

from the theory you obtain this linear differential equation

$$I\,\ddot\theta+k\,\theta=0$$

hence
$$\omega^2=\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^2=\frac{k}{I}\quad\Rightarrow
I=k\,\left(\frac{T}{2\,\pi}\right)^2$$

this means that to obtain the inertia $~I~$ you have to measure the period $~T~$ of the oscillation .

notice

to obtain linear oscillation the length of the rod   must be much bigger then the radius of the rod and of course you have to know the stiffness $~k~$ of the rod. addition the proband  must be mounted symmetric to the torsion  axes.